# Why does the combobox throws error when button associated with its event is clicked

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Basic rundown of program: connected to a database. Combo box is populated with a terms list, after you select a term a get term button is pressed which populates a listview and then returns total balance due in a text box at the bottom of the form.

The Combobox populates, but when the btn is pressed catch ex throws an error along the lines of string cannot be converted to integer(occurs on the form design code). I'm not quite sure where I've gone wrong. It doesn't seem to catch anything else anywhere.

I'll include the code below

```
Imports Payables
```

Public Class Form1

```
Dim invoiceList As List(Of Invoices)
Dim termList As List(Of Terms)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadComboBoxes()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadComboBoxes()
    termList = TermsDB.GetTermsList
    cboTerms.DataSource = termList
    cboTerms.ValueMember = "TermsID"
    cboTerms.DisplayMember = "Description"

End Sub



Private Sub btnGetInvoice_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetInvoice.Click
    Dim invoiceList As List(Of Invoices)
    Dim TermsID = CInt(cboTerms.SelectedValue)


    Try
        invoiceList = InvoicesDB.FindInvoiceByID(TermsID)
        txtTotalBalanceDue.Text = FormatCurrency(InvoicesDB.GetBalanceDue())
        If invoiceList.Count > 0 Then
            Dim invoice As Invoices
            For i = 0 To invoiceList.Count - 1
                invoice = invoiceList(i)
                lvInvoices.Items.Add(invoice.InvoiceID)
                lvInvoices.Items(i).SubItems.Add(invoice.VendorID)
                lvInvoices.Items(i).SubItems.Add(invoice.InvoiceNumber)
                lvInvoices.Items(i).SubItems.Add(invoice.InvoiceDate)
                lvInvoices.Items(i).SubItems.Add(invoice.InvoiceTotal)
                lvInvoices.Items(i).SubItems.Add(invoice.PaymentTotal)
                lvInvoices.Items(i).SubItems.Add(invoice.CreditTotal)
                lvInvoices.Items(i).SubItems.Add(invoice.TermsID)
                lvInvoices.Items(i).SubItems.Add(invoice.DueDate)
                lvInvoices.Items(i).SubItems.Add(invoice.PaymentDate)

            Next
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("There is no info on this account")
            Me.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
        Me.Close()
    End Try


End Sub




Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

```
Public Class Invoices
Dim m_InvoiceID As Integer
Dim m_VendorID As Integer
Dim m_InvoiceNumber As String
Dim m_InvoiceDate As Date
Dim m_InvoiceTotal As Decimal
Dim m_PaymentTotal As Decimal
Dim m_CreditTotal As Decimal
Dim m_TermsID As Integer
Dim m_DueDate As Date
Dim m_PaymentDate As Date


Public Sub New()

End Sub

Public Property InvoiceID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_InvoiceID
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_InvoiceID = value

    End Set
End Property

Public Property VendorID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_VendorID
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_VendorID = value

    End Set
End Property

Public Property InvoiceNumber() As String
    Get
        Return m_InvoiceNumber
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_InvoiceNumber = value

    End Set
End Property

Public Property InvoiceDate() As Date
    Get
        Return m_InvoiceDate
    End Get
    Set(value As Date)
        m_InvoiceDate = value

    End Set
End Property

Public Property InvoiceTotal() As Decimal
    Get
        Return m_InvoiceTotal
    End Get
    Set(value As Decimal)
        m_InvoiceTotal = value

    End Set
End Property

Public Property PaymentTotal() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_PaymentTotal
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_PaymentTotal = value

    End Set
End Property

Public Property CreditTotal() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_CreditTotal
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_CreditTotal = value

    End Set
End Property

Public Property TermsID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_TermsID
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_TermsID = value

    End Set
End Property


Public Property DueDate() As Date
    Get
        Return m_DueDate
    End Get
    Set(value As Date)
        m_DueDate = value

    End Set
End Property

Public Property PaymentDate() As Date
    Get
        Return m_PaymentDate
    End Get
    Set(value As Date)
        m_PaymentDate = value

    End Set
End Property




'Create a function BalanceDue to return the BalanceDue
Public Function GetBalanceDue() As Decimal
    Return m_InvoiceTotal - m_PaymentTotal - m_CreditTotal
End Function
```

End Class

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Public Class InvoicesDB

```
Public Shared Function FindInvoiceByID(ByVal TermsID) As List(Of Invoices)

    Dim invoice As New Invoices
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = PayablesDB.GetConnection
    Dim invoiceList As New List(Of Invoices)
    Dim selectStatement As String = "SELECT InvoiceID, VendorID, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal,PaymentTotal,CreditTotal,TermsID,DueDate,PaymentDate FROM Invoices WHERE TermsID=@TermsID"
    Dim selectCommand As New SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection)
    'add the parameter to the parameter collection of the command object
    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TermsID", TermsID)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader
        If reader.Read Then
            invoice.InvoiceID = CInt(reader("InvoiceID"))
            invoice.VendorID = CInt(reader("VendorID"))
            invoice.InvoiceNumber = CInt(reader("InvoiceNumber"))
            invoice.InvoiceDate = CDate(reader("InvoiceDate"))
            invoice.InvoiceTotal = CDec(reader("InvoiceTotal"))
            invoice.PaymentTotal = CDec(reader("PaymentTotal"))
            invoice.CreditTotal = CDec(reader("CreditTotal"))
            invoice.TermsID = CInt(reader("TermsID"))
            invoice.DueDate = CDate(reader("DueDate"))
            invoice.PaymentDate = CDate(reader("PaymentDate"))

        Else
            'that means the invoice is not found
            invoice = Nothing 'this means the vendor object no longer exists
        End If
        reader.Close()
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
    Return invoiceList
End Function

Public Shared Function GetBalanceDue() As Decimal 'aggregate 
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = PayablesDB.GetConnection
    Dim selectCommand As New SqlCommand()
    selectCommand.Connection = connection
    selectCommand.CommandText =
        "SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal) " &
        "AS BalanceDue FROM Invoices" &
        "WHERE TermsID=@TermsID"
    connection.Open()
    Dim balanceDue As Decimal = CDec(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar)  
    connection.Close() 
    Return balanceDue
End Function
```

End Class

```
Public Class Terms
Dim m_TermsID As Integer
Dim m_Description As String
Dim m_DueDays As Integer

Public Sub New()

End Sub

Public Property TermsID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_TermsID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_TermsID = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Description() As String
    Get
        Return m_Description
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_Description = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property DueDays() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_DueDays
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_DueDays = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Public Class TermsDB

```
Public Shared Function GetTermsList() As List(Of Terms)
    Dim termList As New List(Of Terms)
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = PayablesDB.GetConnection
    Dim selectStatement As String =
        "SELECT TermsID,Description,DueDays " &
        "FROM Terms " &
        "ORDER BY Description"
    Dim selectCommand As New SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection)

    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Dim term As Terms
        Do While reader.Read
            term = New Terms
            term.TermsID = CInt(reader("TermsID"))
            term.Description = reader("Description").ToString
            term.DueDays = CInt(reader("DueDays"))
            termList.Add(term)
        Loop
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Throw ex
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
    Return termList
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: Which catch is being executed? I see like 3 there. I think you've posted too much code

Comment: I have to agree that that's too much code.  You need to spend a bit of time narrowing down where the actual issue is.  If you don't know how to do that then do a bit of reading on debugging practice.

Comment: It is hard to trace anything in your code since your declarations don't include types: `FindInvoiceByID(ByVal TermsID)`. The only place I see at this time is `Dim TermsID = CInt(cboTerms.SelectedValue)`. Your `SelectedValue` may be not what you think. And besides, why not placing some debugging in catch instead of re-throwing exception needlessly?

Comment: Write `Option Strict On`, `Option Explicit On` and `Option Infer Off` at the top of your vb files. This would catch most problems at compile time before runtime.

Comment: Put a Breakpoint on the first line of each of your `Catch` block to identify which code block raised the exception. Then put a breakpoint in the first line of the related `Try` block, then run the debugger again and use the step by step to monitor at what time, which line of code, which variable is causing the exception...

Answer (score 0):

I think your button is triggering the page load event, and you are losing the selected combobox value.

Do you have a text value as the first option in the combobox? That would cause the conversion error you're seeing.

Avoid binding the combobox on postback with something like

```
If ispostback = false Then
LoadComboBoxes()
End If
```

Comment: Yes there is a text value. Ex. In the combo box it will list Net Due 10 days, Net Due 20 Days, etc.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at your btnGetInvoice_Click subroutine and then display CInt(cboTerms.SelectedValue) in the watch window? This line is the first thing I would rule out as the error source. If this is the error, I think you'll be able to avoid it by using isPostBack = false.